# Modifying variables inside generate statements

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, hdl

I am trying to write the Verilog code for a multiplexer module, that has a parametrized number of inputs. I am aware that you can pack the inputs together and use the select input to slice that packed variable but I want to use a binary tree structure for my multiplexer.

The problem lies in using auxiliary variables to properly index inner wires (interm_w), **meaning I need to be able to modify certain integer variables after each iteration of my inner for loop, but I don't know how**. These variables include P, M, and K.

```
module multiplexer_v2(input_data_array, select, output_data);

    parameter WIDTH = 16;
    parameter NUMBER_OF_INPUTS = 8;
    parameter SELECT_WIDTH = $clog2(NUMBER_OF_INPUTS);
    
    localparam INTERMEDIATE_WIRES_COUNT = interm_value(SELECT_WIDTH, NUMBER_OF_INPUTS);  // this is a function, that works correctly.

    input [SELECT_WIDTH-1:0] select; 
    input [WIDTH-1:0] input_data_array [0:NUMBER_OF_INPUTS-1];

    output [WIDTH-1:0] output_data;

    wire [WIDTH-1:0] interm_w [0:INTERMEDIATE_WIRES_COUNT-1]; 

    genvar i;
    genvar j;
    
    int K = NUMBER_OF_INPUTS / 2; 
    int M = NUMBER_OF_INPUTS; 
    int P = 0; 

    generate 
        for(i = 0; i < SELECT_WIDTH; i=i+1) begin 
            for(j = 0; j < K; j=j+1) begin
                multiplexer_2_input #(
                    .WIDTH(WIDTH)
                    ) mux_i (
                        .input_0(interm_w[P + j * 2]),
                        .input_1(interm_w[P + j * 2 + 1]),
                        .select(select[SELECT_WIDTH - i - 1]),
                        .output_data(interm_w[M + j])
                    );
            end

            P = M;                      // line 51 is here
            M = M + K;                   
            K = K / 2;                  
        end
    endgenerate

endmodule
```

I have tried using datatypes such as localparam, int, integer, parameter, and genvar for these variables, and moving around their initialization, but I face the same errors each time:

```
** Error: (vlog-13069) .../multiplexer_v2.sv(51): near "=": syntax error, unexpected '='.
** Error: .../multiplexer_v2.sv(51): (vlog-13205) Syntax error found in the scope following 'P'. Is there a missing '::'?
```

I would greatly appreciate any help I can get.

The `interm_value()` function is as follows:

```
function int interm_value(input int select_width, input int number_of_inputs);
    begin
        int i;
        int interm_value;
        int K;
        interm_value = 0;
        K = number_of_inputs;
        for(i = 0; i < select_width; i=i+1) begin 
            interm_value = interm_value + K;
            K = K / 2;
        end
        return interm_value + 1;
    end
endfunction
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the syntax errors is that variables require **procedural assignments** (from within an `always` block, for example).  But, you are not doing that.

One approach to debugging problems associated with `generate` `for` loops is to manually unroll the loop.

In your code, the outer loop iterates 3 times.  Removing the loop code, you are left with these assignments for `M` and `P`:

```
int M = NUMBER_OF_INPUTS; 
int P = 0; 

P = M;
P = M;
P = M;

M = M + K;                   
M = M + K;                   
M = M + K;
```

Those assignments should be inside a procedural block.  Also, as you can see, it doesn't make much sense to assign the same value to `P` multiple times.

With that explanation, I recommend trying to design something simpler without the loops at first.